# Macbook Pro weight increased after battery replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

After my battery died I have replaced it in Authorized Service Provider. This costs nearly 140$.
However after replacement I noticed that the weight of my Macbook Pro Retina (Mid 2014) has been significantly increased. Is it something I should worry about or there is a chance that they put some not genuine battery into my device? Is there any way to check this? Has anyone had the same experience?

Comment: how much does the weight differ from the number in the specifications on the apple site? a charged battery does weigh more than an empty one, but I would be impressed if you could feel the difference

Comment: @dennismuys, It certainly sounds reasonable that a charged battery weighs more then a discharged battery however I'd love to see some factual quantitative comparative information on the subject.  That said, I too would be impressed if one could feel the difference. :)

Comment: @user3439894 it is quite a scientific explanation but here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34424 :)

Comment: "...feeling the nanograms..." wow!

Comment: You didn't say which Mid 2014 The MacBook Pro you have so here's the weight specifications for both. The MacBook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014 weights 3.46 lbs and the MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014 weights 4.46 lbs. _And lets assume that's with a fully charged battery._  Which one do you have and how much does it weight?

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I weighed my MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013, which has a specification weight of 4.46 lbs, on a scale checked with a calibration weight, and it weighed 2006 grams or 4.422473 lbs. So unless you had an accurate weight before the battery replacement to compare with, you might not be able to tell unless the weight differential is appreciable in comparison.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your comments. I will weigh my MacBook Pro Retina 2015 and compare the weight with the specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what the weight of the MacBook Pro *should* be from Apple's specifications and compare with the current weight of your machine. If it turns out that your machine *is* heavier, you can then do something about it.